# paypal trial payment plugin wordpress

Tags: paypal, trial

Hi from what i've seen on most topics is that to sell a product on paypal with lets just say a 7 day trial period which automatically takes payment after the 7th day, customers need to pay at least $1 initially.

I have a wordpress website which i'd like to add a trail paypal purchase for one of my digital products. i like it to work like this.

1. customer chooses to take on a 7 day free trial
2. they checkout with a paypal account which they do not need to make any initial payments however agree that they will be charged after seven days if they do not cancel their trial.
3. after the 7th day, paypal automatically charges their account.(given they do not cancel trial)

Is this possible to do and are there any current plugins for wordpress available which can achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely possible using PayPal's Express Checkout API with Recurring Payments, but I don't know of any existing plugin that handles that correctly right now.  You'd need to build a custom plugin for WP to do it, but it would be a pretty simple one to build.